# How to edit a file on a remote Raspberry Pi from Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, raspberry-pi, edit, remote-access

I am using Cygwin on Windows 10 to remotely connect to a Raspberry Pi. On the RPi I have scripts that I need to maintain. Currently, I connect with SSH and just use the native VI on the Pi. Needless to say this is a painful experience once you are used to using gVim. Alternatively, I edit locally and then copy the edited files over to the Pi. But this is cumbersome when done a lot of times.

How can I make the RPi file(s) available for editing on my Windows environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use open source software such as [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/). Then create a [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) session. After that, you can browser in the filesystem of your server, localize the file you want to edit. You can do right click and open the file in your Windows environment with the editor of your choice.

At least is what I use in my work environment dealing with Linux servers and Windows as a main host.

Comment: Thanks. Found this seconds after posting the question.

Comment: I didn't mention, but you just need to save the changes in your favorite editor and it will update the latest version of your file. At the end, you won't feel a difference if the file is in your host or somewhere else.

Comment: Apparently, when you create a new file, it will only get created on the remote FS when you *save* the newly opened editor window.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code can do this. [Raspberrypi.com have an article about this](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/coding-on-raspberry-pi-remotely-with-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: Thanks, I am not using VS. Can you comment on how easy it is to set up the environment for doing this? Can't judge from the linked article.

Comment: It should be quite easy. It should take less than 5 minutes after Visual Studio Code (Visual Studio Code is not the same as Visual Studio) is installed

Answer (score 0):

Found [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), which seems to do the trick very nicely!

---

**Update 1:**

One thing to note is, that WinSCP does not really edit the file remotely. It transparently copies it to a local temp directory and edits the copy. When changes are saved, it copies the edited file back on the remote source.

This works fine, unless the connection to the remote host is interrupted. Then, an orphan copy of the file is left in the temp local folder, and possibly the user editing the file has no way to know. When the connection is restored, the copy is no longer linked to the remote file.

---

**Update 2:**

The open-file sync seems to be maintained after network interruption and network changes. My observation above may be restricted to a host reboot. I will keep track of that and update if necessary.

Comment: *"When the connection is restored, the copy is no longer linked to the remote file"* – That's not really correct. When the connection is restored, you can still upload the file. But not, when you close WinSCP meanwhile.

Comment: Mmm.. my scenario was more specific so maybe the comment is too general. I had to reboot the RPi, and when it was back online, the files were not in sync anymore.

Comment: Restart and connection loss are almost indistinguishable events from client (WinSCP) point of view. WinSCP can upload edited file even after the restart. If you have a different experience, consider posting new question or asking at WinSCP support forum.

Comment: Thanks. I'll track it next time a restart is required. In the meantime, I verified that when a connection is restored, even after changing network (working over VPN or via LAN), the file does remain in sync. Might be that what I observed was a singular anomaly. Will see next time.